# could not encode subject with japanese character

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, jakarta-mail, mime

I have a jsp form with subject, content fields which accepts input from user. The program sends out a mail. Here both the fields are set as String objects. After sending mail characters in japanese or chinese are coming as junk characters. If subject as "english" it is working fine.

This is my code

```
// create a message
    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
if(subject != null)

        msg.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");
        //msg.setSubject(subject);//commented to take care of email

    // create the Multipart and add its parts to it
    //MimeMultipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
    MimeMultipart mp = new MimeMultipart("alternative");

    if(body != null)
    {
        // create and fill the first message part

        MimeBodyPart mbp1 = new MimeBodyPart();
        mbp1.setText(body);
        mbp1.setHeader("Content-Type","text/html;charset=utf-8");
        mbp1.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "quoted-printable");
        //mbp1.setContent(body, "text/html");
        mp.addBodyPart(mbp1);
    }
```

I had given subject as `漢字  test message` in the subject field and sending mail. I am getting junk characters for japanese characters. So I am getting message subject as `?? test message`

But still getting some junk characters in subject when I get mail.

Comment: What is the page encoding in the header of the jsp page? What encoding is the browser using?

Answer (score 1):

How was the subject string created?  Did it take into account the character encoding used by the user's browser when sending the form data?  Did you verify that the string contains the correct Unicode character data?